# Implementing NSCopying in subclass of NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary, nscopying

I want to have subclasses of `NSManagedObject` as keys of an `NSDictionary`. Therefore, I have to conform to `NSCopying` and implement `copyWithZone:`.

At first I though I would have to do something similar to this:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone{
     return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Thing" inManagedObjectContext:self.context]
}
```

This however, will have the side effect of inserting something new into my database, which I want to avoid.

What's the best way of of implementing `NSCopying` in `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: `NSDictionary` requires its keys to be immutable. That's why the type is `id<NSCopying>` rather than just `id`. Instances of `NSManagedObject` don't match that contract. Perhaps there's another approach that would be a better fit for the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of `NSManagedObject` is mutable, which does not make it a very good candidate for a dictionary key (this is of course why `NSDictionary` copies key values – if the original key is mutable the copy will not change).

So do you wish to use the *current* value of your managed object as a key, or associate an object with the managed object itself regardless of its current value?

If the latter then you should consider using the managed object's `objectID` property as your key, this property uniquely identifies a managed object. The type of this property is `NSManagedObjectID`, a class which implements `NSCopying`.

HTH

Comment: It would be great if you can give an example :)

Comment: @coolly - an example of what? What the answer says is given `NSManagedObject *mobj` and `NSMutableDictionary *dict` then `dict[mobj.objectID]` is valid and as `objectID` uniquely identifies a managed object this is effectively "keyed by managed object". HTH

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `NSCopying` on `NSManagedObject` is not a good idea. As you've found, they don't fit that model. The fact that an instance is linked to its managed object context and from there to the persistent store means that copying doesn't make sense unless you **do** want to duplicate it. Duplication, of course, is the *whole point* of `NSCopying`.

@CRD made some excellent suggestions. Another approach, depending on your needs, is to use `NSMapTable` instead of `NSDictionary`. It's similar to `NSDictionary` but the differences include weakly referenced keys that don't need to conform to `NSCopying`.

Comment: In general, if we want to have another copy of nsmanaged object. Using this new copy I want to change the values. Is NSCoying good idea for my use case?